# How can I convert an integer representing EPOCH time to a timestamp in Athena (Presto)?

Tags: sql, datetime, epoch, presto, amazon-athena

I have a table where the datetime is stored as varchar but represents the EPOCH time (e.g. 1556895150). How can I get that value to be recognized as a timestamp in Athena / using Presto? something like a dateadd function would work but Athena doesn't have dateadd (I envisioned something like dateadd('second',expressoin,'1970-01-01 00:00:00'. A simple CAST(expressoin as type) does not work here because EPOCH isn't a recognized datetime data type.

Answer (score 8):

You can use [`from_unixtime()`](https://trino.io/docs/0.172/functions/datetime.html#from_unixtime):

```
presto> select from_unixtime(1556895150);
          _col0
-------------------------
 2019-05-03 07:52:30.000
(1 row)
```

Comment: doesn't work because `1556895150` is stored as varchar

Comment: Just cast the epoch to bigint before calling `from_unixtime`: `CAST(epoch as bigint)`